# CRUD in hibernate giving table not mapped exception

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am trying to implement CRUD operations in hibernate.However I am getting "Table not mapped" error. And also,Query is coming as deprecated in my code.
As far as I know,the mapping of table is done in this way only.Then,what is the problem here?

**Code**

```
public void deleteTeacher(String name) {
    Transaction tx = null;
    Session session = Utility.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from vi where name=" + name);
    //Teacher teacher=(Teacher)session.get(Teacher.class, name);
    Teacher teacher = (Teacher) query.getSingleResult();
    session.delete(teacher);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: vi is not mapped [from vi where name=Aayushi]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:658)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:102)
    at DAO.deleteTeacher(DAO.java:45)
    at MainClass.main(MainClass.java:37)
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: vi is not mapped [from vi where name=Aayushi]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:541)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:650)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: vi is not mapped
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3696)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3585)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:720)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:576)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189)
    ... 9 more
```

And the configuration classes are

**teacher.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Teacher" table="vi">

        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="name" column="name"  />
            <key-property name="subject" column="subject" length="10" />
        </composite-id>


    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String should be between `''`, so your query should look like this :

```
Query query=session.createQuery("from vi where name='" + name + "');
```

---

But to avoid any syntax error or SQL Injection, you have to use :

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from vi where name=:name");
query.setParameter("name", name);
```

---

**Edit**

Why you simply don't use :

```
//no need to select your object before you delete it
//Query query = session.createQuery("from vi where name=" + name);
//Teacher teacher=(Teacher)session.get(Teacher.class, name);
//Teacher teacher = (Teacher) query.getSingleResult();

//just make a delete query directly
String hql = "DELETE FROM vi WHERE name= :name";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("name", name);
int result = query.executeUpdate();
```

Avoid to select before you delete, it can cause this error if your result is null.

Comment: even with that I am getting constraint violation exception. The link to my github code is https://github.com/aayushis12/Hibernate Please help

Answer (score 0):

In HQL you have to work with class names, not with table names, so oyur query must be:

```
"from Teacher where name="+Name
```

Also you should use Parameter binding, to prevent SQL injection

Comment: If I am doing the class name then I am getting ConstraintViolationException  @Jens

Comment: `ConstraintViolationException` means that you have a foreign key, that is not known

Comment: @YCF_L Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what I am doing wrong as I am implementing it for the first time.Please help.Here's the link to my github repository https://github.com/aayushis12/Hibernate @Jens

Answer (score 0):

You are  making some poor assumptions here given your model.  Your `Teacher` model uses a composite key of `name`, and `subject`but yet your code assumes that locating a `Teacher` by name would net a single row result and that just isn't always going to be true.

You either need to adjust your data model and force `name` to be unique across all your `Teacher` entities, which again in a real-world situation doesn't make sense or modify your removal code to account for this.

The following code assumes Hibernate 5.2 so it may require some small tweaks but the premise remains precisely the same regardless:

```
final List<Teacher> teachers = session
   .createQuery( "FROM Teacher t WHERE t.name = :name", Teacher.class )
   .setParameter( "name", teacherName )
   .getResultList();

for ( Teacher teacher : teachers ) {
  session.remove( teacher );
}
```

To @YCF_L's point about the *select before delete*, this is actually **not** a problem if your code accounts for the fact that the query's results *can* be empty.  But because as follow real-world scenarios above that multiple teachers *could* have the same name, it won't give you an error because the returned `List<>` will either be empty at which the delete for-loop is skipped or contain values and execute the delete for-loop.

As pointed out, you *could* blindly execute the delete without fetching the data if you'd rather and it would look very similar.

```
int deleteCount = session
  .createQuery( "DELETE FROM Teacher t WHERE t.name = :name" )
  .setParameter( "name", teacherName )
  .executeUpdate();
```

In this scenario, you can use the return value `deleteCount` to log how many teachers were removed or execute some specific code if the value is perhaps *not* what you expected.

Lastly, while others have pointed out the benefits of using parameter bindings to avoid SQL injection, parameter bindings are also important for a host of other reasons.

For example, bind parameter SQL can be optimized, planned, and cached by your database and reused for future queries.  When you introduce the actual values into the SQL directly, most database platforms cache the query as-is, thus you only gain this benefit if you supply the SQL exactly the same as before with the same parameters.